JMETER -USING Json extractor, in every thread extract another value, and I want each thread use its own value, how can I do that?
I have a JMETER load test, I use with JSON extractor, I have 30 threads, each one of them run on another data, I want that each variable use in own thread.
For example: each of thread run on another customer, I extract the birth date, and for every customer it's another response.
How to do that? Can someone help me?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

As per JMeter Variables documentation:

Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

So you don't have to do anything.
If JSON Extractor returns multiple values and you want to use different value on each subsequent request either go for ForEach Controller or use __V() and __counter() functions combination.

thanks for your answer
I understood that too,
But in fact I see that it sends me the same values in all THREADS
What could cause this?
